# integration assertions into tested class

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit

Why it is bad idea to integrate test assertions into tested class?

For example something like:

```
class SomeClass {
  function add($a) {
    return $a + 1;
    }

  function test_add($TestCase) {
    $TestCase->assertEquals($this->add(1), 2);
    $TestCase->assertEquals($this->add(2), 3);
    }
}
```

And then some framework run over all test_* functions passing them TestCase object

what is wrong in this approach? Why all frameworks tends to separate class implementation code and test assertions?

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be size of the class in doing this.  I have found as a rule of thumb that I write 3 lines of test code for each line of actual code.  So you class size would increase by 300%.

The other issue is organization.  Your tests are going to be interspersed amongst the classes methods.  It is going to be even more difficult to put things some place that is easy to find.

Along with, our class is now doing a lot more things than it used to be.  It is now performing whatever functionality that we require of it and it is also testing that the functionality is correct.  Those being two different things suggests that they should really be two different classes.

Comment: thanks. similar was my first thoughts. Concerning organization. For me it is much more simpler when testing code is along with implementation than looking/remembering where testing code is for specific function

Comment: Your test code should be in a similar structure for as your source code, so directories that your code would be stored in would be in the same sort of structure in your test directory.  That is how most major projects have them organized.